# Omniauth + Linkedin (invalid_signature)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, linkedin-api

I'm using facebook and linkedin authentications with omniauth. I have replaced the keys for both facebook and linkedin (provided by facebook and linkedin). Facebook works like a champ, linkedin gives me an invalid_signature error even though I'm using the api credentials linkedin provided. Is there something I'm missing with the linkedin api? Has anyone run into similar problems and come up with a solution.

I have the following omniauth gems installed

- gem 'omniauth'
- gem 'oauth2'
- gem 'omniauth-twitter'
- gem 'omniauth-facebook'
- gem 'omniauth-linkedin'

In /config/initializer/omniauth.rb I have

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, 'XXX', 'XXX', :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
    provider :linkedin, 'XXX', 'XXX'  
end
```

I have also tried

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, 'XXX', 'XXX', :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
    provider :linkedin, 'XXX', 'XXX', :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::LinkedIn  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably solved this by now, but for future searchers the `omniauth-linkedin-oauth2` gem is what you'll want: https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2/